# Mygate Payment Error in mobile device PHP

Tags: php, payment-gateway

I am using mygate payment gateway for one of my client website. When i am doing payments from website it is working fine. But when i am trying the same in the mobile device then i am getting Error like Invalid GatewayID.

https://github.com/MyGateGlobal/SampleCode/tree/master/Virtual/3DSecure/php

I am using this code in this link. please let me know if any one knows the solution for this.Thanks in advance.